# Nginx isn't saving any logs

Tags: nginx

I developed an application connected to nginx server. I am trying to save all the access logs and the errors logs but it's not working. My nginx configuration looks like this.

```
    server {
access_log /var/log/nginx/access-default.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error-default.log;

   listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.19.1.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

nothing is saved in both files(access-default and error-default), what could be wrong?

Comment: The configuration looks fine which implies that `nginx` is not using it. Use `nginx -T` to test your configuration and see exactly which files `nginx` is reading.